# Embed value of counter loop within a directory name

Tags: autoit

I'm attempting to embed the current value of an AutoIt counter loop into a directory name. I'm running 1000 iterations of an analysis and need to ensure the output from the statistical software doesn't overwrite itself. Here's my code:

```
$counter = 0
Do
    FileCopy("C:\Users\Lambeezy\Documents\Folder\ReferentGroup.txt", "C:\Users\Lambeezy\Documents\DifferentFolder\"$counter")
    $counter = $counter + 1
Until $counter = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [Documentation - Language Reference - Operators](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_operators.htm):

> `&` Concatenates/joins two strings.
>
> `&=` Concatenation assignment.

AutoIt [allows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30309114/4157124) concatenation of string to integer. Example using [For...To...Step...Next](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/For.htm) loop:

```
Global Const $g_iMax     = 5
Global Const $g_sPathSrc = 'C:\Users\Lambeezy\Documents\Folder\ReferentGroup.txt'
Global Const $g_sPathDst = 'C:\Users\Lambeezy\Documents\DifferentFolder\'
Global       $g_sPathCur = ''

For $i1 = 1 To $g_iMax

    $g_sPathCur = $g_sPathDst & $i1

    FileCopy($g_sPathSrc, $g_sPathCur)

Next
```

Alternatively [`StringFormat()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringFormat.htm) can be used:

```
Global Const $g_iMax     = 5
Global Const $g_sPathSrc = 'C:\Users\Lambeezy\Documents\Folder\ReferentGroup.txt'
Global Const $g_sPathDst = 'C:\Users\Lambeezy\Documents\DifferentFolder\%s'
Global       $g_sPathCur = ''

For $i1 = 1 To $g_iMax

    $g_sPathCur = StringFormat($g_sPathDst, $i1)

    FileCopy($g_sPathSrc, $g_sPathCur)

Next
```

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339495/4157124).

Answer (score 0):

It's described in the language reference here: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_operators.htm

> `&` Concatenates/joins two strings. e.g. `"one" & 10`    (equals "one10")

```
$counter = 0 
Do 
    FileCopy("C:\Users\Lambeezy\Documents\Folder\ReferentGroup.txt", "C:\Users\Lambeezy\Documents\DifferentFolder\" & $counter) 
    $counter = $counter + 1 
Until $counter = 5
```