# Hexadecimal to decimal

Tags: numbers, hex, decimal, autoit, definition

I have to convert a hexadecimal number to decimal, but don't know how. In the AutoIt documentation (pictured below) some constants (being assigned hexadecimal values) are defined:

[image: a hexadecimal number from AutoIt's documentation]

`0x00200000` hexadecimal (underlined in image) equals `8192` decimal (this is the true conversion). But convertors return `2097152`. I have to convert another hex value (`0x00000200`), but convertors get it wrong. How to correctly convert it?

When I use the definition `$WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` (or a hexadecimal value), it doesn't work. If I use an integer I believe it will work.

Comment: 8192 is 0x2000, the value you have *is* 2097152 which is the same as the windows WS_VSCROLL constant

Comment: You have learnt wrong. `0x00200000` is not decimal 8192. You can verify this yourself using Windows Calculator (put it in programmer's mode using the *View* menu). Check the *Hex* radio button, type in `200000`, and then click the *Dec* button. When reading hex numbers, you can drop any leading zeros - `0x00200000` is the same as `0x200000`, and `0x00000200` is the same as `0x200`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Documentation - Language Reference - Datatypes](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_datatypes.htm):

> In AutoIt there is only one datatype called a Variant. A variant can
>   contain numeric or string data and decides how to use the data
>   depending on the situation it is being used in.

Issuing:

```
ConsoleWrite(0x00200000 & @LF)
```

demonstrates stated behavior. Use [`Int()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Int.htm) in case of conversion requirement:

```
#region Hex2Dec
Global Const $dBin1 = 0x00200000
Global Const $iInt1 = Int($dBin1)

ConsoleWrite($iInt1 & @LF)
#endregion

#region Dec2Hex
Global Const $iInt2 = 8192
Global Const $dBin2 = Hex($iInt2)

ConsoleWrite('0x' & $dBin2 & @LF)
#endregion
```

Related functions include:

- [`Int()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Int.htm)
- [`Number()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Number.htm)
- [`String()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/String.htm)
- [`StringToBinary()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringToBinary.htm)
- [`StringToASCIIArray()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringToASCIIArray.htm)
- [`StringFromASCIIArray()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringFromASCIIArray.htm)
- [`Binary()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Binary.htm)
- [`BinaryToString()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/BinaryToString.htm)
- [`Ptr()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Ptr.htm)
- [`HWnd()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/HWnd.htm)