# Euro symbol in SciTE4AutoIt3 displayed as x80

Tags: autoit, symbols, euro

The Euro symbol, when running an .au3 file in SciTE4AutoIt3, is represented as `x80`. Example:

[image]

What is it and why does it happen?

Comment: Are you using the Scite4Autoit or do you use SciteLite? In my Scite console there is no problem showing the € symbol.

Comment: I found the cause of this behavior and when changed in SciTEGlobal.properties value of **output.code.page=0** from 65001 to 0 was € displayed again.

Answer (score 0):

> ### What is it …

As per [Documentation - Intro - Unicode Support](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/unicode.htm):

> There are a few parts of AutoIt that don't yet have full Unicode support. These are:
>
> …
>
> Console operations are converted to ANSI.

- `€` (ANSI/[Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set)) equals:

  - `x80` (hexadecimal),
  - `128` (decimal).

> ### … why does it happen?

As per [Documentation - Language Reference - Datatypes](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_datatypes.htm):

> In AutoIt there is only one datatype called a Variant. A variant can
>   contain numeric or string data and decides how to use the data
>   depending on the situation it is being used in.

Issuing `ConsoleWrite(0x80 & @LF)` [demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304690/converting-8-digit-hexadecimal-number-to-decimal/30309114#30309114) stated behavior ([SciTE4AutoIt3](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-script-editor/)'s behavior may differ from regular SciTE). In SciTE4AutoIt3 provided code returns:

```
   €

   €
```

Also, <kbd>ALT</kbd> + [ <kbd>0</kbd> - <kbd>1</kbd> - <kbd>2</kbd> - <kbd>8</kbd> ] produces `€`.