# How to convert a string to a number

Tags: autoit

Is there a toInt, or parseInt function?  There appears to be a StringToBinary, but I don't need a binary representation, I just want the number.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30309114/4157124).

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, that `Number()` works in one case unexpected. Strings will converted to 0, but "0" also. You have no chance, to see the difference. It's written in the help file (`A string beginning with letters has a numeric value of zero.`), but it is not satisfactory.
I've made my own function, that exactly works, like `Number()`. But if you pass an expression, that is a string or starts with a string, this returns an numeric value of your choice (default: 0xDEADBEEF) and sets @error to 1.

```
; #FUNCTION# ====================================================================================================================
; Name ..........: _Number
; Description ...: Works like "Number()", but avoids to convert a string to number 0!
; Syntax ........: _Number($_Expression, $_Flag)
; Parameters ....: $_Expression    - An expression to convert into a number.
; ...............: $_iErrReturn    - The numeric return value in error case. Default: 0xDEADBEEF
; ...............:                   You get also the default value by passing "Default" or empty string instaed.
; ...............: $_Flag          - Can be one of the following:
; ...............:                   $NUMBER_AUTO (0) = (default) the result is auto-sized integer.
; ...............:                   $NUMBER_32BIT (1) = the result is 32bit integer.
; ...............:                   $NUMBER_64BIT (2) = the result is 64bit integer.
; ...............:                   $NUMBER_DOUBLE (3) = the result is double.
; Return values .: Success           The converted number, if $_Expression is a number or starts with a (un/signed) number.
; ...............: Failure           The Value from "$_iErrReturn", sets @error = 1   $_Expression is a string or starts with a string.
; Author ........: BugFix
; Remarks .......: In contrast to Number(), you get only a number, if $_Expression is a number or starts with it.
; ...............: Because 0 is also a number, Number() give unclear results:
; ...............: Number("foo") returns 0. Number("0") returns also 0. "0" converts to the real number 0, but "foo" also??
; ===============================================================================================================================
Func _Number($_Expression, $_iErrReturn=0xDEADBEEF, $_Flag=0)
    If $_iErrReturn = Default Or $_iErrReturn = '' Then $_iErrReturn = 0xDEADBEEF
    If StringRegExp($_Expression, '^(-\s\d|-\d|\d)') Then
        Return Number($_Expression, $_Flag)
    Else
        Return SetError(1, 0, $_iErrReturn)
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>_Number
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, use the `Number()` function.

`Number("5")`  becomes 5.